# jquery - crop image with "cropper" - in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to implement the https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper plugin. I've implemented it with  bootstrap and I'm trying to make it so that the user can press a "crop button" and the user will see only the cropped part of the image - inside the image.  The demo uses a modal box and this line of code:

```
 $('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').html(result);
```

this will show find open a modal and put the result image  (result) as html in the modal body. Then user can close and proceed as normal. I want to achieve the same -except no modal box. This approach will not work because it overrides all of the html code and the plugin doesn't work any more. I'm thinking I may have to replace the source image itself with the result. Any solutions to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your original image has to be in a container element like a div. You can select this div with `$("thedivId")` and call `html(result)` on this div.

Comment: It does get the cropped part, but after this it's not possible to do any other operations on the image

Comment: What are these other operations?

Comment: F.ex undo, clear, rotate. They use the src image and image id to point to the image and do these operations.

Comment: So you could change the `DOM-Id` of the result image to the old id from orignal image.

Comment: You can replace the original image with the result so on the result should be a DOM-Image-Node